# Lock crosshairs for mulitple jquery FLOT charts

Tags: jquery, flot

I have 4 different jquery FLOT charts on a page. The x-axis is in time format and all 4 charts have the same time interval along the x axis. I want to be able to set and lock the crosshair of the last 3 charts to the first one when a checkbox is set. I can't figure out how to do this with plot.setCrosshair(pos.x,pos.y).

Any ideas??? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [syntax](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.crosshair.js?r=220) for `setCrosshair` is:

```
plot.setCrosshair({x: xpos, y: ypos});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUKvk/).

Comment: Hey Mark, is it possible to animate the crosshair-ie- i nedd to reposition the crosshair automatically and linearly in one direction from left to right...ie as soon as my graph is rendered, the vertical line should move from left to right automatically as if it is scanning the area